# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: laravel, post, routes

I'm getting this error after posting the data.

Route;

```
Route::post('/classified/location', 'ClassifiedController@locationPost')->name('location-post');
```

Form;

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/classified/location">
@csrf
```

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared your route cachce yet? Like `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: have you declare csrf token? like {{ csrf_fields() }} in your view file.

Comment: <form class="form" method="post" action="/classified/location">
@csrf

Comment: yes i have run the artisan command

Answer (score 1):

Please check your route file to make sure that you haven't defined the same route twice, in that case later will replace the prior so make sure route definition is unique and exactly once.

Also if you anyway are naming your routes then use the name itself to target it so use:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{ route('location-post') }}">
```

Also, make sure you don't define two or more routes with the same name.

Comment: There is only one route with the same name.

Comment: What do you mean the same name? You have more one routes with the name "location-post"?

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tag like that:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{route('location-post')}}">
```

**OR**

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{url('/classified/location')}}">
```

Comment: @bhdrnzl: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: @bhdrnzl: You have two same route name ? (i.e location-post)

Comment: no not.. I have already added a picture, there is no other route with the same name that will collide with that name.